# SurrealDB functions within CONTENT statement

Tags: surrealdb

Is it possible to use the "time::now()" function when doing a CONTENT statement? E.g.

```
CREATE stuff CONTENT $data;
```

$data being a rust BTreeMap. At the moment its inserting the string of "time::now()" rather then running the function at the time of insertion. Im assuming its because my BTreeMap is sending it as a string but not sure how to change that.

```rust
fn stuff_here(media: NewMedia) -> BTreeMap<String, Value>  {
  let data: BTreeMap<String, Value> = [
    ("name".to_string(), media.name.into()),
    ("created_at".to_string(), "time::now()".into()), // This is a string
  ].into();
  let vars: BTreeMap<String, Value> = [("data".into(), data.into())].into();
  vars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a Rust BTreeMap as the $data but you can do this:

```
CREATE stuff CONTENT {"created_at":time::now()};
```

The $data needs to be JSON like `{"created_at":time::now()}`